feols instrument a variable with interaction
Suppose I want to run y~i(group, x) and instrument x with z. How can I do that with feols?
I have tried feols(y~0|0|i(group,x)~z, df) but it does not work, and  feols(y~i(group,x)|0|x~z, df) produces output but I don't think this is the desired one. The output of the interaction is net of the effect of x.
